# Unable to read tag lib on jsp

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp-tags

HI I am using Spring MVC 3.0 Framework .When i am trying to display something through jsp i am getting an error saying Unable to read TLD "META-INF/spring-form.tld" from JAR file ,though the jar file is present ..

Following is the code on jsp :

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main_style.css" type="text/css"></link>

<script  language=Javascript>

    var indexVal=1;

    var fields = document.getElementsByName("languages");
    function getLang(){
        for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++)
        {
            alert(fields[i].value);
        }
    }
    function addLang(){
        var newLang = '<td> <select name="languages"><c:forEach var="item" items="${languageList}"><option><c:out value="${item.displayText}"/></option></c:forEach></select> <a href="#" onclick="addLang();return false;">+</a> <a href="#" onclick="removeLang(this); return false;">-</a> </td>';
        var table = document.getElementById("langTable");
        var trElement = document.createElement("tr");
        trElement.innerHTML = newLang;
        table.appendChild(trElement);
```

And list of jars used by me is as follows :

- eclipselink-jpa-modelgen-2.3.0
- eclipselink-2.3.0
- javax.persistence-2.0
- org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql_1.0.0
- aopalliance-1.0
- commons-dbcp-1.4
- commons-pool-1.5.6
- mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin
- HIbernate support jars
- jstl11 jars
- Spring 3.0 jars

Comment: The error which i am getting on jsp is a s follows :

Unable to read TLD "META-INF/spring-form.tld" from JAR file "jndi:/localhost/NewFms/WEB-INF/lib/spring-webmvc-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar": java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified

Answer (score 0):

spring-form.tld is found in spring-webmvc jar. Make sure you have it in your classpath.

Comment: My Project already contains 
spring-webmvc-3.0.6.RELEASE jar and
spring-webmvc-portlet-3.0.6.RELEASE jars